# Can I ask how to efficiently check if a JavaScript list is missing elements?

Tags: support, scope

I have a [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) question that goes like this: *"How do I efficiently check if a list of consecutive numbers is missing any elements?"* (I didn't ask it yet.)

As in I have `[1,2,4,8,9,10]`.

When one element is missing it's simple (i.e. it's easy(er) to detect that number `3` is missing), but for consecutive missing numbers it's not that straightforward (at least for me.. should I add a loop, can I do it some other way, etc.).

I initially had 2 attempts at solving this, 1 failed and 1 successful but not elegant. While writing the question, I found a 3rd solution that I like, and I was thinking if it's appropriate to ask this question and, besides answering it myself with the 3rd solution, maybe someone else gives me an even better one (performance/memory wise).

Is it on-topic?

I have [the draft almost set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r1oR.png). When I wrote about the ideal array it hit me that I can compare my array with an ideal one and do the check in one iteration (this being the third solution).

Comment: Do you intend to include code from any or all of the 3 potential solutions?

Comment: @jpp - yes of course. I have [the draft almost set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r1oR.png)

Comment: I say: go ahead! There may be refinements which the `[javascript]` tag watchers may suggest. But this looks like a good question.

Comment: Yes, it is on-topic. Make sure you add the attempted solutions. If possible create code snippet

Comment: If you have code that works, and your question is whether there's a more efficient way, it might be better off on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MrLister It's more of a "which algorithm to go for" kind of question, not if I used the appropriate standards in my code or anything like that. (that is, if I don't misunderstand codereview site's purpose)

Comment: @Adelin is right here, codereview is not simply for question that have working code :) I could not find any obvious duplicate for that question, so if it can be very clear that you are looking for *proof*, as in benchmark, as opposed to opinions on what's more efficient, that should be good!

Comment: You should also define your somewhat vague terms (what does *elegant* and *efficient* mean)....as mentioned benchmark standards should be included or this might  be construed as *opinion-based*. But thanks for asking on Meta first,

Comment: Alright then, [I posted it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50274554/how-to-efficiently-check-if-a-list-of-consecutive-numbers-is-missing-any-element). Thanks for the constructive comments

Comment: When you're asking about a specific question you're thinking of asking it would be better to put *the actual content of the question*, formatted as a quote block, in your post. Off-site links to pictures of text are not OK on meta, either!

Comment: So, you had a clear on-topic question with three solution proposals, and you asked here whether you can ask it, now you got 17 upvotes and it's in the "Hot Network Questions". Nice use of meta-effect, I guess? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: if you have to post the question to ask permission on meta _before_ posting the question on the main site, now we have 2 problems. You have almost 3k rep, you should _know_ what a good question is. This one is of course okay

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre with the huge list of close flags available that a 3k rep user is aware of, you start to be paranoid :)

Comment: i wish people would stop to loose time on trying to do "elegant" code when they have a working code already. Half of the time, their vision of "elegant" is using one-liners that fewer people understand, and with logic behind the functions tending to be less efficient than a basic loop. Also, if you don't know how to do something, how do you know enough to judge the code's elegance?

Comment: @Kaddath *if you don't know how to do something, how do you know enough to judge the code's elegance* through intuition. In time, with enough practice, you can just sense there's a definite better way because you feel it's stupid the way you did it.

Comment: @Adelin it was not specifically aimed at you, hope you didn't read it that way :) just that i noticed lots of OPs tend to accept the "more educated-like functions" that often condense the code and make it less readable, without consideration of performance and share-ability of the code. There's no shame producing simple code, every day work coding is often like this.

Comment: Uh, if the array is sorted then `array.length === array[array.length - 1] - array[0] + 1`?

Comment: Wait, answering the question this meta question is about in comments!?! How would future readers find this information?

Comment: Is there an use case for question? Or just random thoughts of solving problems? 